# What function changes a post's timestamp?

Tags: timestamp

What function changes a post's timestamp? I created a post from frontend script, but I need to add a date picker to set the date of the visit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to submit the following information to set a custom date

```
$_POST['aa'] // Month
$_POST['mm'] // Day
$_POST['jj'] // Year
$_POST['hh'] // Hour
$_POST['mn'] // Minute
$_POST['ss'] // Second
```